# Unity Web Player shows as uninstalled using Pipelight on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, firefox, pipelight

I am attempting to get Unity Web Player to work using Pipelight on Chromium. I've enabled the plugin, used various user agents, including Safari 5/OS X, but I continue to get 'You need to install Unity Web Player' on various platforms. I've upgraded all my packages and tried different browsers, including Firefox. What should I do next?

Comment: What url were you visiting?

Comment: http://www.kongregate.com/games/flippfly/race-the-sun

Comment: Don't know what's wrong. Won't work for me either.

Comment: Can you use Unity anywhere?

Comment: I have the same behavior in Firefox.

Comment: Ah, my bad. I missed the fact that you tried other browsers. Chromium is the only one where it's certain that it won't work. On another note, I was under the impression that you would have to install Unity Web Player in Wine or Windows (it's not the same as Silverlight/Pipelight).

Comment: I've taken out the Chromium tag and added the Firefox tag, since it's known that Pipelight (and any NPAPI plugins) will no longer work in Chrome(ium). Last I checked, NPAPI is still supported in Firefox.